# Recently assigned variable loses its value in the next line

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, liferay-6

I am creating a Liferay portlet in Liferay Developer Studio (which is Eclipse) and found a very, very strange behavior.

In one JSP, every time some specific variable is set, its variable has its value changed to `null` in the next line. This is so strange that I felt that I should make a screencast of it - and it is [in this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2wU5FUZgf8M).

The class `AnoterFieldComparator` extends `OrderByComparator` from Liferay, as seen below. This problem just happened to `OrderByComparator` subclasses as well, although this makes no sense to me.

```
public class AnoterFieldComparator extends OrderByComparator {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        Example example1 = (Example)o1;
        Example example2 = (Example)o2; 
        return Integer.parseInt(""+(example1.getAnotherField() - example2.getAnotherField()));
    }
}
```

(Yes, there is a typo. It was just an experiment :) )

The project can be seen [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0Bw9sT8pzNEH7ZjczNmFkM2ItNWVkNi00ZTdhLTk0ODktMmEwZWZiMWZjMjA5) and [here](https://bitbucket.org/brandizzi/novo-exemplo-portlet/overview). I know the question is not that well written, but I am pretty amazed, usually only novices talk about this kind of behavior, and they are wrong most of the time.

Comment: There's still a value in the `value` column; are you sure it's `null`?

Comment: No, it was not. The answer below clarifies the situation, fortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the toString method of AnoterFieldComparator ( or its super class )?

The value column in you screen cast does not go to null just the box down below which is the string representation of this class, at the end of the video you can still see to the right of comparitor the class and the object id, so the variable is not null just the to string method either returned null (0x0) or the string "null".

Comment: You are right. I overrode the `toString()` method on `AnoterFieldComparator` and got the expected result. Not only this, the original `toString()` was returning `null` exactly because a relevant method was returning `null` and should be overridden. I became curious about why `toString()` was returning `null`, found the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.liferay.portal/portal-service/6.0.4/com/liferay/portal/kernel/util/OrderByComparator.java#87), understand the class better and solved my problem. Thank you!